# How to classify a data cube based on centroids?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-image

I`m trying to classify a cube of data based on centroids, it is like a stack of images, one on top of each other. I want to iterate one image at a time, classify that image adn then move to next one. Seems simple, but I cant get it to work. I can do it with one image only, when I try with a cube it throws an error:

---

```
IndexError   Traceback (most recent call       last)
<ipython-input-18-b1b39d6397bc> in <module>
 18         print(i,nx,i/nx*100)
 19         for j in range(0,data.shape[1]-1,step):
---> 20             s = np.array(B[k,i,j]).ravel()
 21             class_id = np.argmin(np.sum(np.abs(centers-s), axis=1))
 22             result_image_centers[k,i,j]=class_id

IndexError: index 372 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 372
```

I realize my centers is a vector of format (5, 64), Where it has 5 classes of 65 point each.
My cube of data has the shape: (2601, 372, 436)

## classify using centers

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
result_image_centers = np.zeros_like(data)
```

## Sliding window

```
nx = data.shape[0]
ny = data.shape[1]
nz = data.shape[2]
step = 1
window_shape = (1, 1, 1)

B = view_as_windows(data, window_shape)

for k in range(0,data.shape[2],step):
    for i in range(0,data.shape[0],step):
        print(i,nx,i/nx*100)
        for j in range(0,data.shape[1],step):        
            s = np.array(B[i,j]).ravel()
            class_id = np.argmin(np.sum(np.abs(centers-s),axis=1))
            result_image_centers[k,i,j]=class_id
```

Basically I want to slide a window over each array/image classifying each point accordingly to its closest center. Doing one image/array at a time, then iterate to next other on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating `k, i, j` over `data.shape[2]`, `[0]`, `[1]`, but then accessing `result_image_centers[k, i, j]`. Either your iteration limits should change (to `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`) or your indexing order should change (to `result_image_centers[i, j, k]`).

Comment: thanks for the answer, u r right, silly mistake mine.